# Trying to create a Journal in Android Studio but App Crashes

Tags: java, android

Upon opening the first activity of my app in Android Studio, app opens fine. I copied and pasted the same main activity code to open the journal activity, and changed the variable names that were needed, but app crashes upon opening the journal up.

here is the code for opening up the journal:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button buttonJournal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        buttonJournal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonJournal);
        buttonJournal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openJournalActivity();
            }
        });


    }

    public void openJournalActivity () {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, JournalActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The journal activity I am opening up: (This might be my problem)

```
public class JournalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.add_note_menu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.add_note){

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteEditorActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);

            return true;

        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_journal);

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.anxty", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        HashSet<String> set = (HashSet<String>) sharedPreferences.getStringSet("notes", null);

        if(set == null) {

            notes.add("Example note");

        } else{

            notes = new ArrayList(set);

        }

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteEditorActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("noteId",i);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                final int itemToDelete = i;

                new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                        .setMessage("Do you want to delete this note")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {

                                notes.remove(itemToDelete);
                                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.anxty", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                                HashSet<String> set = new HashSet(JournalActivity.notes);

                                sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes",set).apply();

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                        .show();

                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

LogCat when app crashes:

-06-11 11:55:55.744 6677-6677/com.example.anxty E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.anxty, PID: 6677
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.anxty/com.example.anxty.JournalActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.anxty.JournalActivity.onCreate(JournalActivity.java:79)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.example.anxty">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/anxty_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/anxty_logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".NoteEditorActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".JournalActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" /> <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" /> <!-- Splash Screen Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: which activity is launcher in manifest file?, Check your logs when your app crashes, share snap of that logcat errors.

Comment: @anshul1507 I added the logcat when the app crashes should I add my manifest file as well?